# Passing stdin arguments to executable being debugged with gdb

Tags: bash, macos, gdb, escaping, pipe

I've read many questions/answers here on SO on this topic but none of the solutions worked... I want to pipe a string generated by perl to an executable being debugged by gdb. But I can't even pass an escaped hexadecimal character... I've tried the following "solutions":

1:

```
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) r "\x41"
```

2:

```
perl -e 'print "\x41"' > input.cmd
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) r < input.cmd
```

3:

```
$ gdb --args ./a.out "\x41"
(gdb) r
```

4:

```
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) set args "\x41"
(gdb) r
```

and I also tried many different combinations of escape characters ", /, \, ', ` ... none worked. Solution number 2 is discussed on many posts here on SO but I get "<" as an argument (gdb is escaping everything to a string)

I even tried to no avail to debug bash and set the executable as a minor but the bash crashes...

What am I missing? I'm using gdb 8.0.1 on macOS 10.13

**UPDATE:**

just tried on a linux machine and the solutions above work. I'm guessing the problem is with the bash/gdb interaction on macOS... any ideas?

**UPDATE2:**

**SOLVED**

definitely an issue with bash calls inside gdb on macOS, managed to workaround like this:

```
$ gdb --args ./a.out $(perl -e 'print "\x41"')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>**SOLVED**</strike>

definitely an issue with bash calls inside gdb on macOS, managed to <strike>workaround</strike> like this:

```
$ gdb --args ./a.out $(perl -e 'print "\x41"')
```

**UPDATE - NOW REALLY SOLVED**

@EmployedRussian was right, the problem was in the stdin passing through bash to gdb:

This is a problem with macOS Sierra:
gdb can't start with a shell (bash) if SIP is enabled, so there are two ways of using gdb on Sierra:

> Using gdb 8.0.1 on Sierra:
>
> **OPTION 1:** Disable shell startup on gdb:

```
echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

when I installed and codesigned gdb I did this while following the official wiki (https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) and since forgot. That was the reason I couldn't pass stdin to gdb.

> **OPTION 2:** Disable SIP and leave shell startup enable

```
echo "set startup-with-shell on" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

reboot into Recovery and:

```
csrutil disable
```

This is obviously not recommended but it serves to illustrate where the problem is regarding gdb 8.0.1 usage on Sierra. Hopefully a gdb update will fix this.

Comment: This doesn't do what you asked for: it invokes "./a.out A" and has nothing to do with redirecting stdin. Either this didn't actually solve anything, or your question is completely wrong WRT what you actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: @EmployedRussian it solves exactly what I've asked above: `I want to pipe a string generated by perl to an executable being debugged by gdb.`

Comment: How is your solution affecting `stdin` of the target program? You use "pipe to" to mean something other than what everyone else means by it. To repeat: either your solution is wrong, or your statement of the problem is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> `perl -e 'print "\x41"' > input.cmd`

You could just do `echo A > input.cmd`

This:

```
2
(gdb) r < input.cmd
```

does *exactly* what you ask for (`./a.out` runs and receives a single character `A` on its `stdin`).

> but none of the solutions worked...

You'll have to tell us how you came to that conclusion.

**Update:**

> when I do `(gdb) r < input.cmd` gdb passes two strings as arguments `<` and `input.cmd`

If that is the case, you have a broken GDB, or (more likely) a broken `$SHELL`.

GDB simply invokes `$SHELL -c './a.out < input.cmd'`, and expects your `$SHELL` to perform redirection. If your shell doesn't do that, all bets are off.

You can run GDB under `dtruss -f` and see what GDB does, and what your shell does.

Comment: using perl or echo is irrelevant. when I do `(gdb) r < input.cmd` gdb passes two strings as arguments "<" and "input.cmd": `Thread 2 hit Breakpoint 1, function (variable=0x7ffeefbffbf9 "<") at prog_example.c:16
16  return return_variable;
(gdb) show args
Argument list to give program being debugged when it is started is "< bin/input.cmd".`

Comment: just tried on a linux machine and it works. I'm guessing the problem is with the bash/gdb interaction on macOS

Comment: would have to turn off SIP to use dtruss and I can't reboot right now... In the meanwhile found a solution (question updated).